# How properly delete an activity

Tags: android, memory-management, android-activity

I've written an android application.

So, this is what happens:

1. I've got a listview and if the user taps on a specific row the following code in invoked to create an activity:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClassName( getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".matchView.MatchViewActivity" );
   intent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId );
   startActivity( intent );
   ```
2. Then the activity is started and let's suppose the user return back to the list view by tapping the back button
3. Now he is again in the Listview and can tap the same cell again such that the same activity is started again.

However, the problem is that when I start the activity and I return back with the back button the (now old) activity is not deallocated. It still runs in the background and if the user again taps on the same cell the same acitvity is started again resulting in the same activity running two, three, four and so on times (depending on how often the user taps).

So if the user taps the back button how do I make sure that the activity I started is properly deleted or ended?

Comment: When the back button is pressed, the activity is destroyed... maybe I'm confused by the question, but there won't be multiple instances of an activity if the back button was pressed to leave it (unless you modify `onBackPressed()`)

Comment: Agreed. Please explain how you have determined that "the (now old) activity is not deallocated".

Comment: In the activity itself I create a Runnable/thread which continues to run when I pop the activity with the back button. Therefore, I got the  impression that the activity is not deleted/destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity` will be deleted automatically (when you return back) by system if you are not holding any reference to it.

Better read about [activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)  and [back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question, if you don't intend anymore to use an `Activity`, the correct way of ending it is by calling `finish()`.

This tells the Android SO you don't want to use it again, but don't expect it to be finished immediately. Android keeps the references to both instances and Activities (this ones are instances too) in memory a certain time after finished so if the user reopens that Activity within a short amount of time, it's recovered much faster.

If you are worried about the state in which the Activity is reopened, you can force it to be restarted every time it's reopened. You might find more references in the `Intent` reference page, especially the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` [flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 0):

You can define in the manifest how an activity is launched based on the "launchMode", and you can choose from one of four launch modes:

- "standard"
- "singleTop"
- "singleTask"
- "singleInstance"

It sounds like you want to use, "singleTask" or "singleInstance", which you can read more about under the "android:launchMode" section here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Add finish(); after starting the new activity to delete the current one.